# CSV to HTML Table Script

Tags: html, batch-file, vbscript, html-table, import-from-csv

In any native Windows Programming language (Preferably Batch), is there any way I can convert an CSV Chart into an HTML file as a table? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: All of them. An html table is <table><tr><td>R1C1</td></tr></table> is a one row and one column table.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include the CSV Chart as an example of the the file you want to convert, and a the converted HTML table you're trying to create, and any code you've written so far to do the conversion, including specific questions about the part that isn't working.  If you want to hire someone to do the work for you, there are a lot of rent-a-coder sites available with a simple internet search.

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday. Maybe you can adapt it to your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029285/windows-batch-system-info-to-html

Comment: And if you're looking for a VBScript solution, I answered a question yesterday about treating a CSV file like a database. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024121/vbscript-to-read-lines-from-csv-file-match-data-and-write-to-same-file/22025729#22025729) post. Once you have a recordset, then you can easily loop thru the records and write formatted (HTML) text to a webpage or file.